# Dimension of irreducible components in polynomial ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

I would like to show the following statement:

> Let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra, where $k$ is any field. Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A[X_1,\ldots ,X_n])$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$. Let $X'\subseteq X$ and $Y' \subseteq Y$ be irreducible components respectively of $X$, $Y$ such that the image of $X'$ in $Y$ is included in $Y'$. Then $\dim(X')=\dim(Y')+n$.

For the sake of computing dimensions, we may as well assume that $A$ is reduced. We then consider $\mathfrak{q}$ a minimal prime ideal in $A[X_1,\ldots ,X_n]$, $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal in $A$ contained in $\mathfrak{q}\cap A$, so that we get a map $A/\mathfrak{p} \rightarrow A[X_1,\ldots ,X_n]/\mathfrak{q}$ between finitely generated $k$-algebras that are also integral domains.

In order to prove that $\dim(A[X_1,\ldots ,X_n]/\mathfrak{q})=\dim(A/\mathfrak{p})+n$, I thought one should use the fact that $$\dim(A/\mathfrak{p})=\operatorname{Tr.deg}_k(\operatorname{Frac}(A/\mathfrak{p}))$$ and $$\dim(A[X_1,\ldots ,X_n]/\mathfrak{q})=\operatorname{Tr.deg}_k(\operatorname{Frac}(A[X_1,\ldots ,X_n]/\mathfrak{q})).$$

However, I fail to see what the field of fraction looks like in each case. I assume that we can not just replace the brackets with parenthesis, right?
Also, we can write $\operatorname{Frac}(A/\mathfrak{p})=A_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}}=A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ because $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal and $A$ is reduced, and similarily for $\operatorname{Frac}(A[X_1,\ldots ,X_n]/\mathfrak{q})$. But then again, I fail to understand how the transcendence degree can be easily computed. The fact that $\mathfrak{p}$ may be strictly included in $\mathfrak{q}\cap A$ upsets me.

Any help with this problem would be gladly appreciated. I thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of flatness?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Well then, base changing with respect to $Y'$ you may assume that $Y$ is irreducible. As $X$ is flat over $Y$ the dimension formula you're looking for will follow easily if you prove that every irreducible component of $X$ maps dominantly to $Y$. The easiest way to see this is to notice that if $Y$ is irreductible than $X$ will also be irreducible, as $A$ integral implies $A[X]$ integral.

Comment: In fact you don't even need flatness if you know that $A$ noetherian implies $\text{dim}A[X]=\text{dim}(A)+1$ which follows directly from the hauptidealsatz and the going down if I remember correctly.

Comment: I got it, I was able to conlude now. Both your comments were very helpful for me and helped me put things together.
Thank you very much !